# Finding the matrix of transformation with respect to a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

(I'm sorry about the formatting - can someone help me fix it?)

Consider the bases $$α =\{ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\} $$

of $M_2{_×}_2(R)$ and $$β = \{1, x, x^{2}
, x^{3}\}$$
of $P3(R)$.

Also, consider the function $T : M_2{_×}_2(R) → P3(R) $ defined by 
$$
T\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}= (a − 2b) + (b + c)x − dx^{2} + (a + b + c)x^{3}
$$

Find $\;\;\;[T]^\beta_\alpha\;$ .

I really want to know the general process to solving these problems - my professor described no such thing before assigning a multitude of homework questions requiring it.

Comment: $T(\beta)$ doesn't make sense. You mean to find $T(\alpha)$ maybe?

Comment: The β should be higher, the α lower. My bad

Comment: The notation is not self-explanatory to me, but I assume you're trying to find the inverse of $T$? If so, start by formulating $T$ as a (4x4) matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general process is boringly simple: apply $\;T\;$ to each element of $\;\alpha\;$ and express the outcome as a linear combination of $\;\beta\;$ . Now, take **the transpose** of the coefficients matrix of the above. That thing is $\;[T]_\alpha^\beta\;$ .

Of course, it is easier to say than to understand fully and carry on, so I'll do some and you'll do the rest:

$$\begin{align*}
&T\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}:=-2+x+x^3=&\color{red}{-2}\cdot1+\color{red}1\cdot x+\color{red}0\cdot x^2+\color{red}1\cdot x^3\\{}\\
&T\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}:=x+x^3=&\color{red}0\cdot1+\color{red}1\cdot x+\color{red}0\cdot x^2+\color{red}1\cdot x^3\end{align*}$$

etc. Observe the above two lines of **red** coefficients are your matrix's first two **columns**. Continue now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be a linear transformation, $B$ some basis on the domain, and $B'$ some basis on the codomain. Then the columns of $T$ are simply the coordinates of the images of $B$ under $T$, in the basis $B'$.

For example, let $T$ be some transformation from $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R^3$. Now say we had some basis $a_1, a_2$ of $\mathbb R^2$ and another $b_1, b_2, b_3$ of $\mathbb R^3$. What do we mean by "the matrix of $T$ relative to the bases $(a_i)$ and $(b_i)$"? Well, every element of $\mathbb R^2$ can be represented as a pair of numbers - its coordinates in the basis $a_1, a_2$. Similarly, every vector in $\mathbb R^3$ can be represented as a triplet of numbers. The "matrix of $T$ relative to the bases $(a_i)$ and $(b_i)$" means the matrix such that, when we multiply it by the pair of numbers representing the $(a_i)$-coordinates of a vector $x$ in $\mathbb R^2$, we get the triplet of numbers which are the $(b_i)$-coordinates of $T(x)$ in $\mathbb R^3$.

But the coordinate vector of $a_1$ itself is just $(1, 0)$. So when we multiply this matrix by $(1, 0)$, we should get the coordinates of $T(a_1)$. But hang on, when you multiply a $3\times2$ matrix by $(1, 0)$, you get its first column! So the first column of our matrix is just $T(a_1)$, expressed in the basis $b_1, b_2, b_3$. Similarly, the second column of matrix is just going to be the coordinates of $T(a_2)$.

Thus, your problem reduces to calculating $T(a)$ for each $a\in\alpha$, and finding the coordinates of that object with respect to the basis $\beta$.